# How evaluate this model?

Tags: python, computer-vision

I trained this model in URL : https://github.com/val-iisc/lsc-cnn
in the different dataset and it give me the desired density map
I train it using google colab
but I face 2 problems ..

1. I don't know how to evaluate the model with MAE and MSA
2. I didn't git the actual and predicted ground truth of each image

can you tell me how to solve these problems ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: thank you. I found the solution